# Hiding products with £0.00

Tags: magento2, php, sql

Magento 2.3, how can I hide products automatically via cron for products that have a £0.00 price? I use a 3rd party to calculate prices across my store and when some products cannot be matched in their database it will not calculate the frontend price.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a plugin to change the value of product  status based on price. No need to use a cron.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html